# why webelement's test show unnormal from the view of source code sometimes

Tags: html, selenium, internet-explorer

[the source code that has issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGnRi.png)

[image]

please refer to the picture

there is a select in the page

and I use xpath

```
".//*[@id='edit-comanyinfo-window']//li[text()='20-99']"
```

to locate the element

but sometimes, the text shows like:

```
"
20
-
99
"
```

why?

it does not always show like this

and I know there is other method to locate the element

I just want to understand why!

the some page other time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iu0u.png)

it is normal and the element is "20-99" in the html source code

Comment: please refer to the picture

Comment: this may be due to browser rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

The result you see is the absolute representation of the `WebElement` identified by :

```
".//*[@id='edit-comanyinfo-window']//li[text()='20-99']"
```

Which appears in the [**`DOM Tree`**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) being represented as :

```
"
20
-
99
"
```

Your next question would be then why do we see the element as :

```
20-99
```

It's because of the **`JavaScript`** associated with the **`The HTML DOM (Document Object Model)`**

### Power of JavaScript :

When a web page is loaded, the `Web Browser` creates a **`Document Object Model`** of the page. The **`HTML DOM Model`** is constructed as a tree of Objects as in the figure below :

[image: The HTML DOM Tree of Objects]

With the object model, **`JavaScript`** gets all the power it needs to create a dynamic HTML because :

- **`JavaScript`** can `change` all the **`HTML elements`** in the page
- **`JavaScript`** can `change` all the **`HTML attributes`** in the page
- **`JavaScript`** can `change` all the **`CSS styles`** in the page
- **`JavaScript`** can `remove` existing **`HTML elements and attributes`**
- **`JavaScript`** can `add new` **`HTML elements and attributes`**
- **`JavaScript`** can `react` to all existing **`HTML events`** in the page
- **`JavaScript`** can `create new` **`HTML events`** in the page

The change in the layout of the **`WebElement`** is due to the presence of **`JavaScript`**

Comment: I understand the power of JS,but in chrome

Comment: I understand the power of JS,but it is really wired only sometimes happen

Comment: It is not only about `Chrome` only. Each browser have it's `Engine` which renders the `HTML DOM`.

Comment: and in firefox and chrome and ie ,sometimes my script failed.after checking,i get to know that this situation happens again.not always,only sometimes.maybe the developer do some curse on it

Comment: That's because your `xpath` was not uniquely identifying the `WebElement`. Feel free to raise a new Question with your new requirement.

Comment: i think the xpath is unique in this page .the part [text()='20-99'] can assure that it is the only one, but theissue is that sometimes the browser deal with the html source code in the format ：                                                                          “20                                                                                                                   
 -                                                                                                                  
 99”

Comment: Can you Accept the Answer and raise a new Question as per you new requirement please?

Comment: this is the only question ,why i have to raise another one?

Comment: I already answered to your followup question that your `xpath` is incorrect.

Comment: no !                         the xpath is correct ,you misunderstand!  you  Reverse causation.maybe it is bercause the JS ,but this can not explain all things .it not my expecting answer